# Find all possible ordered groups in a list

Tags: python

Given an ordered list of integers:

```
[1,3,7,8,9]
```

How can I find all the sublists that can be created from original list where order is maintained? Using the example above, I'm looking for a way to programmatically generate these sequences:

```
[[1],[3,7,8,9]]
[[1, 3],[7,8,9]]
[[1, 3, 7],[8,9]]
[[1, 3, 7, 8],[9]]
[[1, 3, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 3, 7], [8, 9]]
[[1], [3, 7], [8], [9]]
[[1], [3], [7, 8], [9]]
[[1], [3], [7], [8, 9]]
...
```

I'm basically looking for a way to generate all the permutations of a list where order is maintained. I can generate all the sublists where there are only 2 sublists in total using this code:

```
def partition(arr, idx):
    return [arr[:idx], arr[idx:]]

l = [1,3,7,8,9]
for idx in range(1, len(l)):
    groups = partition(l, idx)
    print(groups)

[[1], [3, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 3, 7], [8, 9]]
[[1, 3, 7, 8], [9]]
```

However, this code snippets only splits the original list in two and generates all the possible sublists where there are only two sublists. How can I generate all the possible sublists that can be created from original list where order is maintained?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
import itertools

def subsets(seq):
    for mask in itertools.product([False, True], repeat=len(seq)):
        yield [item for x, item in zip(mask, seq) if x]

def ordered_groups(seq):
    for indices in subsets(range(1, len(seq))):
        indices = [0] + indices + [len(seq)]
        yield [seq[a:b] for a,b in zip(indices, indices[1:])]

for group in ordered_groups([1,3,7,8,9]):
    print group
```

Result:

```
[[1, 3, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 3, 7, 8], [9]]
[[1, 3, 7], [8, 9]]
[[1, 3, 7], [8], [9]]
[[1, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 3], [7, 8], [9]]
[[1, 3], [7], [8, 9]]
[[1, 3], [7], [8], [9]]
[[1], [3, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1], [3, 7, 8], [9]]
[[1], [3, 7], [8, 9]]
[[1], [3, 7], [8], [9]]
[[1], [3], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1], [3], [7, 8], [9]]
[[1], [3], [7], [8, 9]]
[[1], [3], [7], [8], [9]]
```

Comment: Seems like you're reinventing the wheel with `subsets`. I'm sure the same thing could be more easily done with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: I suppose you could instead define `subsets` as `for i in range(len(seq)+1): for x in itertools.combinations(seq, i): yield list(x)`. Not sure if you could do it with only one `for` loop though.

Comment: `[item for x, item in zip(mask, seq) if x]` -> `list(itertools.compress(seq, mask))`

Comment: Oh nice, I've overlooked `compress` up until now. TIL.

Comment: This is the only time I've found a use for it.